# Can we access typedef'ed types via an instance?

Tags: c++, types

I wondered,

```
for(std::map<int, double, std::greater<int> >::iterator it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); ++it)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Why am I not able to write this as:

```
for(mymap::iterator it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); ++it)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Of course, typedeffing the map would make the first code less verbose - but that is not my point. The compiler knows the type of `mymap`, so why not let it resolve `mymap::iterator`? Is there a reason why `iterator` is not accessible via the instance?

Comment: `auto` keyword which will be introduced in the new C++ standard will solve this nicely.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`::` is a scope resolution operator that expects type name or namespace name on the left-hand side. It doesn't accept object names on the left-hand side. Allowing this would probably overcomplicate a lot of things in the language.

In fact, if one would to allow something like this, one'd probably attach this functionality to `.` operator, since `.` operator is the one used with objects on the LHS

```
for (mymap.iterator it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); ++it)
```

But this still would unnecessarily overcomplicate things anyway.

In the future C++ standard something like that will become possible through `decltype` keyword

```
for (decltype(mymap)::iterator it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); ++it)
```

P.S. According to Wikipedia article on `decltype`, its availability in qualified-ids was a matter of debate. If I understood it correctly, this usage was eventually voted in.

P.P.S. Also, as @Asha noted in comments, in the future C++ you'll be able to avoid naming the type at all

```
for (auto it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); ++it)
```

Comment: So, is there any other way to access the type `iterator` via `mymap`?

Comment: @AndreyT, mymap::iterator is valid if mymap is typedeffed to std::map<int, double, std::greater<int> >.

Comment: @0xC0DEFACE: I'm referring specifically to the OP's `mymap`. And the OP's `mymap` is an object, not a typedef name.

Comment: @AndreyT: Not overcomplicating things goes against the C++ philosophy.

Comment: @nakiya: Not in current C++. But in the future standard - see above.

Comment: @AndreyT, I see. That would then make the OP's problem trying to name a variable with an existing typename, rather than the problem being his inability to use the scope resolution operator on a typedeffed type, which was his original question?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `auto` when using C++0x instead of `decltype`?

Comment: @0xC0DEFACE: No, what the OP wants is a C++98 way to obtain the effect of C++0x `decltype(mymap)::iterator`, to avoid having to copy-and-paste the type name.

Comment: @Asha: Yes, it is better. It is just that `decltype` does pretty much literally what the OP requested: allows accessing nested type through the object. What `auto` does is not "exactly" what OP requested, but it is a better approach indeed.

Comment: Boost has a library implementation of auto and typeof, worth trying out if you haven't got (or don't want to use) C++0x support in your compiler: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/typeof.html

Comment: @Andrey: actually, in the future C++, you'll probably write `for (auto pair: mymap)` which is much more succinct. By the way, I wish you would not be recomputing `end()` at each iteration of the loop. C++ does not support `purity` and therefore the compiler cannot infer that the result will not change and cache it.

Comment: @AndreyT, I think the inability to form a qualified-id with *decltype* was simply unintuitive and not in accord with the intent of the original proposal (that a *decltype*-expression should behave just like a typedef).

Comment: @Matthieu: recomputing end() is such common practice that almost all containers ensure it's inline and trivial.  And for every weird container where it's not, there's probably another weird container where a cached end() would be invalid after some operation, risking iteration past the new end....

Comment: @Tony: it's trivial, yes, but it cannot be cached. The new range-based for syntax takes care of the issue nicely :D

Comment: @Matthieu: point is it's effectively cached on the container side (and with inlining there are no sides) so there's no performance penalty for optimised code. C++0x will be so nice though... can't wait :-)

Comment: @Tony: ah I understand what you mean. Not all containers though retain the value of `end()` as a member, it may involve (even in trivial cases) additions / multiplications. Though I agree that if inline the cost is minimal indeed :)

Comment: @Matthieu: agreed not all, but for example - all GCC's Standard containers directly return a member variable (consequently and interestingly, `vector::size()` is calculated as a difference, which shifts the issue to those using `for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)` ;-)).  Anyway, given they're templates (and hence defined inside the translation unit) the optimiser's got a chance to see if any intraloop operation on the container might change the values from which `end()` or `size()` are derived....

Answer (score 1):

That iterator is a type which is defined in the scope of map and not part of objects created from map.

Comment: But it could very well have been, if the language had been defined otherwise. The only reason for not being able to ask about "member types" is that there is no way of doing it!